# How long does Google fit data last?

Tags: android, google-fit

While developing an Android app with Google fit api, I have a question about Google fit data.

How long does Google fit data last?

For example, if you accumulated Google fit data on one phone for six years,
I'm wondering if I can see 6 years of Google fit data accumulated on other phones.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean How long it lasts? It depends on your app how long you want to keep it....

Comment: The back end servers should keep the data indefinitely. (until Google decide to stop the service)  As for the caching of the data onto any particular users device it's hard to say but with an internet connections the data should be pull-able from the servers again as required.

Comment: @Ifor indefinitely is an awfully long time. According to the [T&C's](https://developers.google.com/fit/terms): "Google reserves the right to set limits on the length of time content may be accessible on Google Fit. Where reasonable, we will give you notice of those limits within the Google Fit documentation before we set them."